# how to fix error in mysql code while making count trigger after insert

Tags: mysql, sql

i am setting triggerafter_inser and i dont know how to resolve it

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `solocloud_dev_2`$$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS table_10_summary_after_insert $$

CREATE TRIGGER table_10_summary_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON table_10
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DECLARE var INT;
   SET var=0;

   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_10_summary WHERE client_id = new.client_id;

   IF var > 0
   THEN 
       UPDATE table_10_summary SET records = records+1 WHERE client_id = new.client_id;

    ELSE
        INSERT INTO table_10_summary (new.client_id,1);
END$$

DELIMITER$$
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Will var ever be bigger than 0? Or should it contain that count? Or maybe don't count and change to an [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/) statement?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your trigger :

- you need to `SET var` from the results of the query ; as it is now, you are not setting this value
- the `IF` block must be terminated with `END IF`

The following codes compiles successfully **[in this DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aG8j8Ume154WF2WWX3QeAn/0)** :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS table_10_summary_after_insert $$

CREATE TRIGGER table_10_summary_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON table_10
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE var INT;

    SET var = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_10_summary WHERE client_id = new.client_id);
    IF (var > 0) THEN 
        UPDATE table_10_summary SET records = records + 1 WHERE client_id = new.client_id;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO table_10_summary VALUES(new.client_id,1);
    END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```